# How to make use of Facebook JavaScript SDK on a NodeJS project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

I do not know how to make use of the oficial JavaScript SDK on a NodeJS project.

I've installed [pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug) and pasted the SDK in this index page in order to show a Log In Button, but my issue is how to use these tools, like for instance to check if a user is logged in, but in the back-end side, for example:

```
const fb = require('../util/fb')

function index(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Log-in', h1: 'Log-in on Facebook'})
}
```

This is `home.js` file which has methods that are executed depending on the current route:

```
...
const home = require('./routes/home')

app.set('views', './views')
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.get('/', home.index)
...
```

I want, in the `index()`, check if the user is logged in to redirect the user to another page, and eventually, check if the user is logged in in this other page, to redirect back to `index` in case not. How do I do this with Facebook's official JavaScript SDK? I have tried two modules but I found nothing about checking the user's status.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Passport authentication mechanism , it supports multiple authentication techniques like for Google, Facebook ,twitter and many more .

[Passport Facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook)